# Python3.7 how to extract numerical value from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing some CTFs and I made this script:

```
import requests

page = requests.get("http://ctf.slothparadise.com/about.php").text
p_split = page.split("<p>")
p2_split = p_split[3].split("</p>")

print(p2_split)
```

My output from this is:

```
['You are the 135181th visitor to this page.\n      Every thousandth visitor gets a prize.', '\n    </div> <!-- /container -->\n  </body>\n</html>\n']
```

How can I extract the value `135181` out of this list?

Comment: Try `print(p2_split[0].split()[3][:-2])`

Comment: Search for regular expressions, and extraction digits from string.

Comment: @vishes_shell has it right I think, and just to add to that, he is suggesting you don't create a list (i.e. don't use `split` in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `regex`, this is especially easy since it doesn't seem they change 'th' despite the number ending with 1 or 2:

```
import re
import requests

page = requests.get("http://ctf.slothparadise.com/about.php").text
re.findall("\d+(?=th)", page)
```

output:

```
['135335']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this working for any value adapt this:

```
my_split = ['You are the 135181th visitor to this page.\n      Every thousandth visitor 
gets a prize.', '\n    </div> <!-- /container -->\n  </body>\n</html>\n']

visitor_num = my_split[0].split('You are the ', 1)[1].split('th')[0]
print(visitor_num)
```

Actually, I can see similar solutions in the comments as well... hope this works for you!
For future reference, look up using the split function and indexing- it's something you will definitely use again.

Comment: Thank you. Ill defiantly try to look it up.
I used Filip Młynarski answer (print(p2_split[0].split()[3][:-2])) for now.

Comment: No prob.  It's nice to "upclick" what you consider good answers, so please upclick Filips comment and any others you think were helpful.  Welcome to the StackOverflow community :D